# Конвертирование переменной в юникод

Tags: c++, qt, строки

Дело происходит под `Qt`.

```
QString sa = "Warhammer\u00ae 40,000\u2122";
QString dsa = QString::fromLatin1(sa.toLocal8Bit().data());
```

Такой метод не работает, хотя по логике вещей должно работать.
Получаю: `Warhammer? 40,000?`

Если просто использовать

```
QString dsa = QString::fromLatin1("Warhammer\u00ae 40,000\u2122");
```

То на выходе выйдет валидный юникод с трейдмарком.

В чем проблема?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Мне непонятно, что вы пытаетесь сделать. `QString` - это и есть юникод (utf-16).

Оба варианта неправильные (второй вариант не работает в mingw) 
mingw выдает противоположные результаты (второй вариант не работает, а в msvc наоборот).

Вы неправильно инициализируете строку.

`QString` в Qt5 по-умолчанию ожидает строку в utf-8 (из `const char*`).
Но visual studio по умолчанию преобразует `char*` литералы в ANSI (на русской винде это Windows-1251).
По этому получается ерунда.
Способ, специфичный для Qt:

```
QString sa = QStringLiteral("Warhammer\u00ae 40,000\u2122");
```

По сути, `QStringLiteral` добавляет к строке `L""` в MSVC (а в gcc добавляет `u8""`):

```
QString sa = QString::fromWCharArray(L"Warhammer\u00ae 40,000\u2122");
```

Можно передавать utf-8 явно:

```
QString sa ="Warhammer\xc2\xae 40,000\xe2\x84\xa2";
```

Если вы используете с++11 (будет работать только начиная с MSVC 2015, GCC 4.4+, clang):

```
QString sa = u8"Warhammer\u00ae 40,000\u2122";
```

В старых версиях msvc 2010 (недокументированный способ, у меня на 2013 не работает)

```
#pragma execution_character_set("utf-8")
QString sa = "Warhammer\u00ae 40,000\u2122";
```

О господи, какой же бардак в C++ с юникодом :(

Comment: Вопрос был о том как передавать с переменной с типом данных `QString`, просто указание `QString sa = QString::fromWCharArray(L"Warhammer\u00ae 40,000\u2122");` работает даже через `fromToLatatin1`

Comment: Я не понял ваш комментарий. Что передавать? Куда передавать?
Если вы хотите преобразовать `QString` в `const char*`, используйте `toUtf8()` и `fromUtf8()`.
В вашем же коде ошибка именно в инициализации строки.

Comment: вы имели ввиду это http://i.imgur.com/EHzc3P7.png ?

Comment: Добавьте `QStringLiteral` или `QString::fromWCharArray` и вопросики исчезнут.

Comment: Первый определенно не будет работать, так как принимает только текст. Второй не получается у меня.

Comment: Вам и нужно передавать текст!!
`QString sa = QStringLiteral("Warhammer\u00ae 40,000\u2122");
 QString dsa = QString::fromLatin1(sa.toLocal8Bit().data());`

Comment: Вы не совсем понимаете о чем говорите, речь идет о передаче из переменной, а не просто об установке текста. QStringLiteral(var) определенно не будет работать.

Comment: Если вы хотите преобразовать не строковый литерал, а `char*` в QString, то я должен понимать, в какой кодировке текст.
Вы  же привели пример со строковым литералом `"Warhammer\u00ae 40,000\u2122"` и спрашиваете, почему он не работает. Я вам объяснил, почему.
Вы же пытаетесь преобразовать QString в QString. Это не имеет смысла.

Comment: Сделал пример с `QString::fromWCharArray` но вопросики остались. Текст в `Windows-1251`

Comment: Что-то не верится. Приведите код.

Comment: Просто поверьте, либо пишите сами. Уже давно удалил его.

Comment: `L` не имеет ничего общего с юникодом, это просто говорит о том, что результирующая строка будет массивом `wchar_t`, а не `char`. В остальном пост правильный. @MatthewHaig, не хотите иметь головной боли со строками в Unicode просто храните их в отдельном файле, с определённой кодировкой(скажем utf-8) и загружайте их во время исполнения.

Comment: @ixSci `L""` в MSVC это всегда юникод, насколько я знаю. На других компиляторах/платформах это может быть не так.

Comment: `L""` это `wchar_t *` к *unicode* это не имеет никакого отношения.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1810343/is-a-wide-character-string-literal-starting-with-l-like-lhello-world-guarantee
MSVC и GCC преобразует текст в юникод. Конечно, при желании туда можно запихать что угодно.

Comment: @zenden2k, по Вашей ссылке то же самое, что я сказал выше. Никакого преобразования в юникод не происходит, потому что такое преобразования в природе не существует. Есть преобразование между представлениями символов(utf-8, 16, 32 и т.д.). В какое из этих представление преобразует gcc/MSVC? Насолько я знаю - ни в какое, они тупо берут и расширяют каждый символ исходной строки до `wchar_t`

Comment: @ixSci, что значит "тупо берут и расширяют"? У меня исходники в кодировке windows-1251, куда msvc ее расширит? Он преобразует строку в utf-16

Comment: @zenden2k, ну расширить можно просто добавив `0x0` в первый байт, но по поводу студии Вы правы, я только что проверил. У меня исходник в utf-8, но `L""` он преобразовал в корректный UCS-2(может и utf-16, но я сильно сомневаюсь). Так что да, по крайней мере в студии, `L` можно использовать вместо `u`, пока `u` не добавили. Спасибо, не знал.