# Почему Windows не выводит в программах русский текст?

Tags: qt

В общем стараюсь работаю, а Windows не хочет выводить русский текст. Как справиться с этой напастью ?

```
  void start_dialog::slotShowMessage()
{
     m_ptrayIcon->showMessage("For your information",
                         QString::fromLocal8Bit("Запущенна программа  MA_chek \"Выберите аппарат!\" option"),
                         QSystemTrayIcon::Information,
                         3000
                        );
  //tr("Запущенна программа MA_chek \"Выберите аппарат!\" option")
 }
```

Вот листинг . Фаил называется start_dialog.cpp

```
 #include "start_dialog.h"
  #include "ui_start_dialog.h"


   #include <QTextCodec>

   #include <QtGui>


   #include "obmen.h"

  start_dialog::start_dialog(obmen *_obm, QWidget *parent) :
QDialog(parent),
ui(new Ui::start_dialog)
  {
    QAction* pactShowHide =
        new QAction("&Show program MA_chek", this);


  connect(pactShowHide, SIGNAL(triggered()),
        this,         SLOT(slotShowHide())
          );

    QAction* pactShowMessage = new QAction("&Show Message", this);
      connect(pactShowMessage, SIGNAL(triggered()),
        this,            SLOT(slotShowMessage())
       );

  //    QAction* pactQuit = new QAction("&Quit", this);
   //    connect(pactQuit, SIGNAL(triggered()), qApp, SLOT(quit()));

m_ptrayIconMenu = new QMenu(this);
m_ptrayIconMenu->addAction(pactShowHide);
m_ptrayIconMenu->addAction(pactShowMessage);
   //   //    m_ptrayIconMenu->addAction(pactQuit);

m_ptrayIcon = new QSystemTrayIcon(this);
m_ptrayIcon->setContextMenu(m_ptrayIconMenu);
m_ptrayIcon->setToolTip("MA_chek");

slotChangeIcon();

m_ptrayIcon->show();



ui->setupUi(this);
obm = _obm;




  }

  start_dialog::~start_dialog()
 {
    delete ui;
  }

  void start_dialog::on_b_kgasm_show_clicked()
    {
      obm->stor->vibor_ui_dialog =1;
    emit signal_kgasm_show();
    this->hide();
    qDebug() << obm->stor->vibor_ui_dialog ;
   }

   void start_dialog::on_b_spa_show_clicked()
 {
     obm->stor->vibor_ui_dialog = 2;
     emit signal_spa_show();
      this->hide();
     qDebug() << obm->stor->vibor_ui_dialog ;
     }

   void start_dialog::on_b_bt_show_clicked()
 {
obm->stor->vibor_ui_dialog = 3;
emit signal_bt_show();
this->hide();
qDebug() << obm->stor->vibor_ui_dialog ;
 }

 //// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
/*virtual*/void start_dialog::closeEvent(QCloseEvent*)
{
  //    if (m_ptrayIcon->isVisible()) {
   //        hide();
  //    }
}

  // ----------------------------------------------------------------------
  void start_dialog::slotShowHide()
 {
  //    setVisible(!isVisible());
     raise();
 }

  // ----------Проблемма как раз тут эту фразу от выводит краказяблами !!!
  void start_dialog::slotShowMessage()
{
      QTextCodec *codec = QTextCodec::codecForName("Windows-1251");
      QString string = codec->toUnicode("Запущенна программа MA_chek   \"Выберите аппарат!\" option");
      m_ptrayIcon->showMessage("For your information",
                         string,
                         QSystemTrayIcon::Information,
                         3000
                        );
//tr("Запущенна программа MA_chek \"Выберите аппарат!\" option")
  }
 // ----------------------------------------------------------------------
  void start_dialog::slotChangeIcon()
{
    QString strPixmapName = ":/new/prefix1/images/img1.bmp";

     m_ptrayIcon->setIcon(QPixmap(strPixmapName));
}
```

Comment: Чтобы ответить на ваш вопрос, надо знать 
1. В какой кодировке у вас исходные файлы (utf-8, windows-1251). В Qt Creator по-умолчанию utf-8.
2. Какая версия Qt - 4 или 5?

Answer (score 1):

В Qt5 лучше использовать `QStringLiteral`

```
m_ptrayIcon->showMessage("For your information",
                         QStringLiteral("Запущена программа  MA_chek \"Выберите аппарат!\" option"),
                         QSystemTrayIcon::Information,
                         3000
                        );
```

более подробно я уже отвечал [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/427006/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B2-%D1%8E%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4/427022#427022)

Answer (score 0):

```
QTextCodec *codec = QTextCodec::codecForName("Windows-1251");
QString string = codec->toUnicode("Привет");
```

Вроде так должно работать, но не могу посмотреть как именно я делал.

Comment: Не не сработало , но спасибо за ответ   :- )

Comment: А что именно не сработало? QMessageBox таким образом русские строки нормально выводит?

Comment: Да, это 100% рабочий способ.

Comment: в общем весь листинг вам даю )))

Answer (score 0):

Если файлы исходников в utf8 тогда:

```
 QString string = trUtf8("Привет");
```

1251 :

```
 QTextCodec *codec = QTextCodec::codecForName("Windows-1251");
 QString string = codec->toUnicode("Привет");
```